# Como compilar um projeto com Android.mk através de um script.sh?

Tags: android, shell-script, android-ndk

Tenho um projeto simples com código nativo e estou usando o comando manual para compilar `/workspace/android-ndk-r11c/ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-14 TARGET_ARCH_ABI=armeabi NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.`.

No meu projeto tenho o Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

subdirs := $(addprefix $(LOCAL_PATH)/,$(addsuffix /Android.mk, \
        native_code \
    ))

ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi-v7a)
    MY_INCLUDE := ../build/module_armeabi-v7a
endif

ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi)
    MY_INCLUDE := ../build/module_armeabi
endif

ifndef MY_INCLUDE
$(error "You must define MY_INCLUDE before starting build_script.sh")
endif

include $(subdirs)
```

Como viram no arquivo [Android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html) acima, tenho a variável `MY_INCLUDE`, através do `ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)` e de acordo com a arquitetura passada no `TARGET_ARCH_ABI`, posso compilar para diferentes arquiteturas.

Dessa forma com o comando [`ndk-build`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html) consigo compilar perfeitamente, mas preciso que ele compile, não através da *linha de comando* com o `ndk-build`, mas sim através de um *build script* que também passaria a variável `MY_INCLUDE` para o Android.mk.

Como eu poderia compilar executando o arquivo build_script.sh?